# Stored Procedure not pulling SubQuestions (LimeSurvey) SSMS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, limesurvey

Using LimeSurvey to query data from stored procedure, however I can't get type T to pull correctly. Something isn't working with the multiple choice questions with multiple answers (type T). Looking for the answer for it to display results.

Using LimeSurvey to query data from stored procedure, however I can't get type T to pull correctly. Something isn't working with the multiple choice questions with multiple answers (type T). Looking for the answer for it to display results.

```
  USE [LimeSurvey]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_CreateFieldMapBailey2]    Script Date: 8/15/2018 8:21:29 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*
                    Types "L", "!", "O", "D", "G", "N", "X", "Y", "5", "S", "T", "U"

                    Description                     Class Prefix        Legacy Character Code   Parent (if blank assume QuestionModule)
                    5 point choice                  FiveList            5   
                    List (dropdown)                 Select              !                       List
                    List (radio)                    List                L   
                    List with comment               CommentList         O                       List
                    Array                           RadioArray          F                       Array
                    Array(10 point choice)          TenRadioArray       B                       RadioArray
                    Array (5 point choice)          FiveRadioArray      A                       RadioArray
                    Array (Increase/Same/Decrease)  IDRadioArray        E                       RadioArray
                    Array (Numbers)                 NumberArray         :                       Array
                    Array (Texts)                   TextArray           ;                       Array
                    Array (Yes/No/Uncertain)        YNRadioArray        C                       RadioArray
                    Array by column                 ColumnRadioArray    H                       RadioArray
                    Array dual scale                DualRadioArray      1                       RadioArray
                    Date/Time                       Date                D   
                    Equation                        Equation            *   
                    File upload                     File                pipe character  
                    Gender                          Gender              G   
                    Language switch                 Language            I   
                    Multiple numerical input        Multinumerical      K   
                    Numerical input                 Numerical           N   
                    Ranking                         Ranking             R   
                    Text display                    Display             X   
                    Yes/No                          YN                  Y   
                    Huge free text                  HugeText            U                       Text
                    Long free text                  LongText            T                       Text
                    Multiple short text             Multitext           Q   
                    Short free text                 ShortText           S                       Text
                    Multiple choice                 Check               M   
                    Multiple choice with comments   CommentCheck        P                       Check
*/ 
/*
  Author: Thoraya Zedan
  Date: 3/18/2018
  Store procedure to map Lime Survey Questions and Answers.
  Tables used:
     * dbo.lime_questions
     * dbo.lime_groups 
     * dbo.lime_answers
     * dbo.lime_survey<sid> 
*/
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[p_CreateFieldMapBailey2](@surveryid int = '883877')
as
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    /* Check if $sLanguage is a survey valid language (else $fieldmap is empty) */
    Declare @qid int, --Questiond ID
            @sid int, -- Survey ID
            @sqid int, -- Subquestion ID
            @gid int,  -- Group ID
            @scale_id int, 
            @specialtype nvarchar(10), 
            @defaultvalue nvarchar(10),
            @parent_qid int, -- Parent Question ID for SubQuestions
            @type varchar(1), -- Question Type
            @title nvarchar(max), -- Question Title
            @question nvarchar(max), -- Question Text
            @preg nvarchar(max) ,
            @help nvarchar(max),  
            @other varchar(1), 
            @mandatory varchar(1),
            @question_order int,
            @language varchar(20),
            @same_default int,
            @relevance varchar(max),
            @modulename nvarchar(255), 
            @SubQuestionsFound bit,
            @SQL nvarchar(max), -- for dynamic SQL
            @TableName nvarchar(100), -- Table name for survey responses
            @SurveyIDChar nvarchar(100), -- Convert Survey ID from int to varchar
            @column_name nvarchar(100), -- From data dictionary
            @DerivedColumnName nvarchar(100), -- Derived from code
            @ParentQuestion nvarchar(max), -- Parent Question is the main question for the subquestion group
            @Answer_Value nvarchar(max), -- Answer value, not the code
            @Answer_ValueFromCode nvarchar(max), -- Answer value for code based answers
            @stitle nvarchar(max), -- Subquestion Title
            @squestion nvarchar(max), -- Subquestion Text
            @squestion_order int, -- Subquestion Order
            @SubQuestionPaddedNumber nvarchar(10), -- Zero Padded number
            @AnswerColumnName nvarchar(100), -- The response table column name
            @id int, -- reponse ID from the response table
            @ParmDefinition nvarchar(1000) -- Parameter list

    -- Temp Table
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempLimeQuestionAnswers') IS NOT NULL
       DROP Table ##TempLimeQuestionAnswers
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempLimeReponse') IS NOT NULL
       DROP Table ##TempLimeReponse

    Set @DerivedColumnName = '';
    Set @SurveyIDChar = CAST(@surveryid as varchar(100));

    Set @TableName = 'lime_survey_' + @SurveyIDChar

    -- Prep Temp Answer Table
    Set @SQL='Select * into ##TempLimeReponse from '+ @TableName; 
    exec sp_executesql @SQL

    -- Answer Table Cursor
    declare curResponseTable cursor for 
    Select id from ##TempLimeReponse;

    -- Prep Temp Q&A Table 
    CREATE TABLE ##TempLimeQuestionAnswers(
    [id] int null,
    [qid] [int] NULL,
    [Column_Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [parent_qid] [int] NULL,
    [sid] [int] NULL,
    [gid] [int] NULL,
    [type] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [question] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [subquestion] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Answer_Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [preg] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [help] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [other] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [mandatory] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [question_order] [int] NULL,
    [language] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [scale_id] [int] NULL,
    [same_default] [int] NULL,
    [relevance] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [modulename] [nvarchar](255) NULL   
    );

     Open curResponseTable
     Fetch Next from curResponseTable into @id
     While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
       BEGIN
            -- Main Query for Mapping
            declare curMainQuery cursor for
            SELECT [qid]
                  ,[parent_qid]
                  ,questions.[sid]
                  ,questions.[gid]
                  ,[type]
                  ,[title]
                  ,[question]
                  ,[preg]
                  ,[help]
                  ,[other]
                  ,[mandatory]
                  ,[question_order]
                  ,questions.[language]
                  ,[scale_id]
                  ,[same_default]
                  ,[relevance]
                  ,[modulename] 
             FROM dbo.lime_questions as questions, dbo.lime_groups as groups
             WHERE questions.gid=groups.gid AND 
                   questions.language=groups.language AND 
                   questions.parent_qid=0 AND
                   questions.sid = @surveryid
             ORDER BY group_order, question_order;

            Open  curMainQuery
            Fetch Next from curMainQuery into @qid,@parent_qid,@sid,@gid,@type,@title,@question,@preg,@help,@other,@mandatory,@question_order,@language,@scale_id,@same_default,@relevance,@modulename 
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
            BEGIN  
                Set @SubQuestionsFound = 0; -- init value
                -- Derive the column name
                Set @DerivedColumnName = @SurveyIDChar + 'X' + Cast(@gid as nvarchar(100))  + 'X' + Cast(@qid as nvarchar(100)) ; --"{$arow['sid']}X{$arow['gid']}X{$arow['qid']}

                IF @other = 'Y'
                   Set @DerivedColumnName = @DerivedColumnName + 'other'

                -- Is this a comment field?
                IF @type = 'O'  
                    Set @DerivedColumnName = @DerivedColumnName + 'comment' 

                -- Multiple Comment
                 IF @type = 'P'  --$fieldname="{$arow['sid']}X{$arow['gid']}X{$arow['qid']}{$abrow['title']}comment"; 
                    Set @DerivedColumnName = @DerivedColumnName + @title + 'comment'

                    -- Multiple Choice
                 IF @type = 'T'   
                    Set @DerivedColumnName =  @SurveyIDChar + 'X' + Cast(@parent_qid as nvarchar(100))  + 'X' + Cast(@qid as nvarchar(100)) + 'SQ' + ''


                -- is this a subquestion? 
                IF (select count(*) from dbo.lime_questions where parent_qid = @qid) > 0 -- We have subquestions. Use the count not the question type
                   Begin
                        Set @DerivedColumnName = @SurveyIDChar + 'X' + Cast(@parent_qid as nvarchar(100))  + 'X' + Cast(@qid as nvarchar(100)) + 'SQ' + '';
                        Set @SubQuestionsFound = 1;
                        Set @ParentQuestion = @question; -- Since the cursor has parent_id=0 we know this is the parent question. 

                        --Find all subquestions
                        -- Cursor for parent_id 
                        declare curSubQuestion cursor for
                        select qid, title, question, question_order from dbo.lime_questions
                         where [sid] = @sid
                          and  gid = @gid 
                          and  parent_qid = @qid
                        order by question_order;

                        Open curSubQuestion
                        Fetch Next From curSubQuestion into @sqid, @stitle, @squestion, @squestion_order
                        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
                        BEGIN  
                        -- Loop
                            Set @SubQuestionPaddedNumber = Replace(STR(@squestion_order,3), '', ''); -- padd with zeros
                            Set @AnswerColumnName = @SurveyIDChar + 'X' + Cast(@parent_qid as nvarchar(100))  + 'X' + Cast(@qid as nvarchar(100)) + 'SQ' + '';
                            -- Get the answer
                            SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Answer_Value nvarchar(100) output'
                            Set @SQL = 'Select @Answer_Value= ['+ @AnswerColumnName +'] From ##TempLimeReponse where id =' + CAST(@id as nvarchar(100))
                            exec sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @Answer_Value=@Answer_Value output

                            Insert into ##TempLimeQuestionAnswers(
                                   [id],[qid],[Column_Name],[parent_qid],[sid],[gid],[type],[title],[question],[SubQuestion],[Answer_Value],[preg],[help],[other],[mandatory],[question_order],[language],[scale_id],[same_default],[relevance],[modulename])
                            Values(@id, @sqid,@AnswerColumnName, @parent_qid, @sid, @gid, @type, @stitle, @question, @squestion, @Answer_Value,@preg, @help, @other, @mandatory, @squestion_order, @language, @scale_id, @same_default, @relevance, @modulename );
                            Fetch Next From curSubQuestion into @sqid, @stitle, @squestion, @squestion_order
                       END -- curSubQuestions
                       CLOSE curSubQuestion  
                       DEALLOCATE curSubQuestion         
                   End -- Array Questions
                IF @SubQuestionsFound = 0
                   Begin                       
                        -- Get the answer
                        SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Answer_Value nvarchar(100) output'
                        Set @SQL = 'Select @Answer_Value= ['+ @DerivedColumnName +'] From ##TempLimeReponse where id =' + CAST(@id as nvarchar(100))
                        exec sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @Answer_Value=@Answer_Value output
                        -- Check if this is a code
                        IF (select count(*) from dbo.lime_answers where qid = @qid) > 0
                           BEGIN
                                Select @Answer_ValueFromCode = [answer] From dbo.lime_answers where qid = @qid and code = @Answer_Value;
                                Set @Answer_Value = @Answer_ValueFromCode;
                           END 
                        Insert into ##TempLimeQuestionAnswers(
                                [id],[qid],[Column_Name],[parent_qid],[sid],[gid],[type],[title],[question],[Answer_Value], [preg],[help],[other],[mandatory],[question_order],[language],[scale_id],[same_default],[relevance],[modulename])
                        Values(@id,@qid,@DerivedColumnName, @parent_qid, @sid, @gid, @type, @title, @question, @Answer_Value, @preg, @help, @other, @mandatory, @question_order, @language, @scale_id, @same_default, @relevance, @modulename );
                   End      
                Fetch Next from curMainQuery into @qid,@parent_qid,@sid,@gid,@type,@title,@question,@preg,@help,@other,@mandatory,@question_order,@language,@scale_id,@same_default,@relevance,@modulename            
            END -- curMainQuery
            Close curMainQuery;
            Deallocate curMainQuery;        
            Fetch Next from curResponseTable into @id
    End --curResponseTable
    Close curResponseTable;     
    Deallocate curResponseTable;
        -- Replace the Select with an insert statement to place in a table. 
    Select * from ##TempLimeQuestionAnswers;
    -- Temp Table
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempLimeQuestionAnswers') IS NOT NULL
       DROP Table ##TempLimeQuestionAnswers
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempLimeReponse') IS NOT NULL
       DROP Table ##TempLimeReponse
END
```